# Seaborn multiple grouped boxplot based on column names

Tags: pandas, seaborn, boxplot

Let's say I have following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
['x', 42, 50 68 12,
['y', 51, 60 79 22,
['z', 43, 50 58 12,
['w', 46, 70 88 22,
['xy',38, 40 69 22,
['xz',39, 40 49 12
], columns=['system', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

And I want to create a multiple grouped boxplot based on column names (I want to create box plots of columns b, c, d, e and). Is there a way to do this task? I could not find any information regarding this

For example I checked seaborn website and it creates grouped boxplot based on a column values [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html) (`hue="smoker"`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `melt` your dataframe first to change its data structure to a structure that works with seaborn:

NOTE: BELOW CODE will not return boxes on sample data. However, it should work with actual data. With the provided sample data, you won't get a box if you pass a `hue` parameter, because the max size of values in your `system` column is 1. **You cannot have a boxplot with only one value, and that would defeat the purpose of a boxplot. Instead you would probably want a bar or line chart.** In other words, you only have one row for x, y, z, w, xy, xz, etc. In your actual data if you have let's say 600 rows with 100 rows for each value in system, then you would get a grouped box with the below code.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
['x', 42, 50, 68, 12],
['y', 51, 60, 79, 22],
['z', 43, 50, 58, 12],
['w', 46, 70, 88, 22],
['xy',38, 40, 69, 22],
['xz',39, 40, 49, 12]], columns=['system', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df = df.melt(id_vars='system')

sns.boxplot(x="system", y="value", hue="variable", data=df)
```